# bash fill an array of integers from arguments and sort it

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting

I looked everybody but I'm stuck with this code.

For example :
The user calls ./array.sh 3 5 6 2 1
I am supposed to sort (i thought bubble sort) and print the array sorted.

```
    #! /bin/bash
    tab=( $@ )
    define -i temp
    for ((i = ${#tab[*]-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)) ; do
        for ((j = 0 ; i - 1; j++)) ; do
        if [ ${tab[$i]} > ${tab[$i+1]} ] then
            $temp = ${tab[$i+1]
            ${tab[$i+1]} = ${tab[$i]}
            ${$tab[$i]} = $temp 
        fi
    done
    echo ${tab[*]} #print the array
```

But bash is not happy with that, he keeps tellin me that I cannot assing values like that.
What do I do wrong ? Can you help me please ? I looked in a lot of places but there is no way to find the solution.

Thanks you in advance guys.

Comment: Run your script through http://shellcheck.net; most of your problems are simple syntax errors.

Comment: I strongly urge you to fix your errors: that will help your development as a programmer. I also urge you not to reinvent the wheel: `printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort -n` suffices.

Comment: chepner thank you very much for the website, I almost corrected the code when @JohnBollinger showed me the way. for GlennJackman , I know right, but that's an assignment from a very old school teacher, thanks again everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a value to a value (e.g. `${tab[$i+1]} = ${tab[$i]}`); you must assign to a name or to an array element.  Also, you may not have space on either side of the equals sign (`=`) in a bash assignment, except in numeric context.

And you dropped some closing braces.

And you misspelled "declare".

And you need a semicolon or newline between your `if` condition and your `then`.

And you didn't terminate your inner loop.

And you reference a non-existent array element via `${tab[$i+1]}`.

And your inner loop has a constant as its termination condition.

And `${#tab[*]-1}` incorrectly attempts to do math inside the braces delimiting the variable reference.

And you referenced the wrong index variable (consistently) in your inner loop.

And `>` is a redirection operator, not greater than, except in numeric context.

Once you clear up that multitude of errors, you end up with

```
#! /bin/bash
tab=( $@ )
declare -i temp
for ((i = ${#tab[*]} - 1; i > 0 ; i--)) ; do
  for ((j = 0 ; $j < $i; j++)) ; do
    if [ ${tab[$j]} -gt ${tab[$j+1]} ]; then
      temp=${tab[$j+1]}
      tab[$j+1]=${tab[$j]}
      tab[$j]=$temp 
    fi
  done
done
echo ${tab[*]} #print the array
```

which actually works.

Comment: thank you a lot, i am a beginner and i was used to code in c, so bash is really new for me, sorry for wasting your time but I really looked in a lot of places even here. thanks again a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your variable assignment syntax is all wrong.

First, you don't put `$` before the variable being assigned.

Second, you must not have spaces around `=`.

So it should be:

```
temp=${tab[$i+1]}
tab[$i+1]=${tab[$i]}
tab[$i]=$temp
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are working on a class assignment or such and are restricted in how you are allowed to solve the problem.  *For those not so restricted*, here is a simple solution using standard unix tools:

```
#!/bin/bash
( IFS=$'\n'; echo "$*" ) | sort -n
```

Sample usage:

```
$ script.sh 3 5 6 2 1
1
2
3
5
6
```

Explanation:

- `( IFS=$'\n'; echo "$*" )`

  This causes the command line arguments to be printed, one per line.  This is in a subshell so that the assignment to `IFS` does not affect the rest of the script.
- `sort -n`

  `-n` tells `sort` to apply a numeric sort.